# What does this Python shorthand do? {s[:i] + s[i+1:] for s in level for i in range(len(s))}

Tags: python

```
level = {s[:i] + s[i+1:] for s in level for i in range(len(s))}
```

I figured it was the same as this, but it's not the case.

```
for s in level:
  for i in range(len(s)):
    level = {s[:i] + s[i+1:]}
```

Source: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-invalid-parentheses/discuss/75028/Short-Python-BFS

Comment: `{s[:i] + s[i+1:]}` is a set of all elements in `s` except the `i`th.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's functionally equivalent to:

```
new_level = set()
for s in level:
    for i in range(len(s)):
        new_level.add(s[:i] + s[i+1:])
level = new_level
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue that I have faced while achieving this are

- RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration. To avoid this I have used `copy()` functionality `level.copy()`
- And the other one, we can't create an empty set object in Python as we do for list,dict objects. So we must do an absolute instantiation as `new_level=set()`

  ```
  new_level=set()
  level={"one","two","three"}
  for s in level.copy():
    for i in range(len(s)):
        new_level.add(s[:i] + s[i+1:])
  print(new_level)
  ```

Hope it helps.